# CSS / Talwind: how to align an Image on the bottom of a split layout?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a built a split page layout that, is perfectly aligned as it was intended:

[image]

Constructed using:

```
 <div className="flex flex-wrap">

  <div className="w-full md:w-1/2 h-screen overflow-hidden order-last lg:order-first md:order-first">      
  <div className="flex h-screen">
  <div class="m-auto max-w-3xl px-5">

    {TeamData.slice(0, 1).map((item, index) => {
      return (
          <div>
            <h1 className="text-3xl xs:text-2xl md:text-3xl lg:text-5xl xl:text-6xl mb-5">{item.name}</h1>
            <p className="text-xl leading-10 uppercase mb-5 text-gray-700">{item.title}</p>
            <p className="text-xl leading-10 mb-5">{item.bio}</p>
            </div>     
      );
    })}

 </div>
 </div>
</div>

  <div className="bg-green w-full md:w-1/2 h-screen order-first lg:order-last md:order-last">

  <img className=" object-contain h-screen w-full" src={require('../images/johne_doe.png').default} data-aos="fade-up" alt="John Doe" />

  </div>
</div>
```

Upon screen resizing to sizes smaller than 1440px in width, however, the portrait images get considerably offset from the bottom.

[image]

**How can I keep in its bottom alignment on smaller viewports using tailwind?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `object-bottom` to an image tag.

Yoг can find information about `object-{side}` [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/object-position#class-reference)